How can I retrieve checkbox values from a select element in a signup form and store them in a CSV file?
Question:
I'm building a signup form for my website, and I've encountered an issue with retrieving checkbox values from a select element. Here's the structure of my form:
*html
Copy code
<form id="forms" action="signup.php" method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>
    <select id="categories" multiple>
        <option value="category1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="category2">Category 2</option>
        <!-- More options -->
    </select>
    <!-- Checkboxes for each category are dynamically generated within the select element -->
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>*

I want users to be able to select multiple categories for their interests using checkboxes within the select element. When the form is submitted, I need to retrieve the selected categories and store them in a CSV file along with the user's email and password.
How can I achieve this using PHP? Specifically, how can I retrieve the selected checkbox values from the select element and process them in my signup.php script for storing in a CSV file?
Additionally, if there are any best practices or security considerations I should be aware of when handling form submissions like this, I would appreciate any advice.
Thank you!

Only difference in that post is the method the form sends the data. You use POST instead of GET but both should work.
